# Two tables side by side in two column document

Tags: tables, floats, minipage

I need two tables to be placed on top of the page and side by side in a two-column document. Each table should have its own caption, in its own column, and needs to be nicely centered to its column.

So I tried this:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
      \hline
      1 & 2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 4 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{table 1}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
      \hline
      1 & 2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 4 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{table 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

And what it does is actually putting two small `minpage`s at the center of the whole document regardless of any column geometry.

Since I previously used `subfigure` and I know they nicely center in such scenarios I also tried:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
      \hline
      1 & 2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 4 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}
      \hline
      1 & 2 \\
      \hline
      3 & 4 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 2}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
```

The ugly part is that I cannot have separate table captions that way (to the best of my knowledge, I cannot put `table` in `figure`). Nor can I use `captionof{table}` in the `figure` environment.

All in all, what do you suggest? How to have them nicely centered but still to have two separate table captions?

---

Why Mico's answer does not work? Seems like tables are not always centered.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \hrule
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 1 & 2 \\ \hline 3 & 4 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{table 1}
  \end{minipage}\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \hrule
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 1 & 2 \\ \hline 3 & 4 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{table 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-15] % filler text
\end{document}
```

[image: micos_example]

---

Mico provided the solution to this problem; add `%` after each `tabular`. The idea is to suppress the space after `tabular`. That spacing does not work well with `\resizebox`. For more details see the comments to Mico's answer.

Comment: You might try the `floatrow` environment, from the homonymous package.

Comment: Why are you using a `figure*` environment instead of a `table*` environment? And why are you using `subfigure` instead of `subtable` environments?

Comment: @foki - Please see the comment I left below my answer for a suggestion for how to deal with the newly-introduced facts that (a) the natural widths of the tabular environments may exceed `\columnwidth` and (b) you apply the `\resizebox` sledgehammer to force their widths back down to `\columnwidth`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use a `table*` environment (*not* a `figure*` environment), 2 `minipage` environments (each of width `\columnwidth`) within the `table*` environment, and centered `tabular` environments and `\caption` directives within each `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline 1 & 2 \\ \hline 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 1}
\end{minipage}\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline 1 & 2 \\ \hline 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-15] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that does not render the same for me. If you put the `tabular`'s into `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{...}`, doesn't it look a little bit off from center. Doesn't it look a little bit more to the left?

Comment: I mean, it does look centered when the tables are small, but when I maximize their size, it seems like they are not centered. Or maybe `resizebox` screws it up.

Comment: There is an automatic \columnsep gap between columns.  Try adding an \hrule inside the minipage to show the column width.

Comment: @JohnKormylo But how is `columnsep` an issue here? It just looks like the `tabular`'s are not centered within the `minpage`s but start from the left margin. In fact, that's exactly what your experiment with `hrule` shows.

Comment: @JohnKormylo See my updated questions.

Comment: @foki - My LaTeX code implemented the (somewhat implicit!) layout rules you provided in your initial query; one of them was that the widths of the `tabular` environments are smaller than `\columnwidth`. If that is *not* the case, as you make clear in your comments above and in your updated query, and if instead the natural widths of the `tabular` environments *exceed* `\columnwidth`, two slight tweaks are needed if you still want to place the `tabular` environments side by side (via `\resizebox` instructions): change both instances of `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabular}%`. That's all.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - The OP's decision (which, frankly, I failed to anticipate!) to want to encase the `tabular` environment in a box of width `\columnwidth` -- via a whack with the `\resizebox` sledgehammer -- causes a secondary problem, *viz.*, LaTeX no longer removes the whitespace after `\end{tabular}` automatically, even if `\centering` is in effect. In such an extreme case, it's necessary to suppress the offending whitespace character *manually*, by changing `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabular}%`. For what it's worth, I'm not too embarrassed by this particular failure of mine...

Comment: I don't think LaTeX ever removed whitespace after `\end{tabular}`.  \par does that.  Anyway, the \columnsep was just a guess.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - I'm afraid I've expressed myself (inadvertently!) quite  misleadingly. I meant to say that if `\centering` is in effect *and* i the width of the `tabular` is less than `\linewidth`, then it doesn't matter if one forgets to place `%` immediately after `\end{tabular}`. (Check it for yourself to verify.) But this runs into trouble if the `\resizebox` sledgehammer is introduced into the game.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the explanation. My intent was not to embarrass you and I am sorry if any of my comments were too harsh.